# Fonts are not embedded into a pdf?

Tags: 11.04, fonts, pdf, latex

I have created a pdf file using the `pdflatex` command but some fonts are not embedded into it.  Please see the output of `pdffonts`. I have also checked "updmap --edit" to see whether the option "pdftexDownloadBase14" is true or not. It is true. But, still some fonts are not emebedded. Please help me to resolve this. 
[image]

Comment: I vaguely remember that some font cannot be embedded for license problems. Absolutely not sure if is that the case.

Comment: One way I found is that convert the pdf into ps using pdftops command and again convert that ps into pdf using "ps2pdf14" solves the problem. However, the quality of the pdf is reduced. This is not best solution for this.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question on [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be the most relevant question for askubuntu, but I'll try to answer it nevertheless: You probably included graphics in your document that use the Helvetica font (a common example are the axis labels for figures created by Matlab), right? 
If you used Helvetica in your document (e.g. with `\usepackage{helvet}`), the Helvetica replacement *Nimbus Sans L* would be used instead.

Embedding the fonts from external figures is not possible at the moment (it should work if you make sure that the external figures embed the fonts themselves, though!).

Therefore, as suggested in the comments, the only solution seems to be to do a PDF->PS->PDF conversion, e.g.:

```
pdf2ps file.pdf file.ps
ps2pdf14 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dEmbedAllFonts=true file.ps file.pdf
```

Unfortunately, hyperlinks for example will not survive this transformation.

See this question on the (more relevant) tex.stackexchange sister site:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex

Answer (score 3):

Another (I believe, better) alternative is to use ghostcript:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=${file}_FONTS-EMBEDDED.pdf ${file}.pdf
```

It is better because the resulting `pdf` is smaller and keeps a good behavior in text copying. In fact, this method embeds other fonts, in place of the original. But, the resulting `pdf` will have all fonts embedded. I found this method [here](https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/?p=1500).